Aligning the radio buttons with the radio button text in android
This is the design for my radio button in a radio group. The dynamic text that is updated programmatically, it is divided into two lines.
The radio button here is aligned to the top of the radio button text whereas I want it to align in the middle android.

 <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_32"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_1"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_group_rectangle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        </RadioGroup>


This is how the radio buttons are added programatically
 private fun addRadioButtons(){
            Enum.values().forEach {
            val radioButton = RadioButton(context)
            radioButton.layoutParams= LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            TextUtils.setTextToRadioButtons(requireContext(),radioButton,getString(viewModel.getOptions(it.days)),
                viewModel.getDateRange(it.days))
                radioButton.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.radio_button_rectangle)
            if (it.days == 14) radioButton.isChecked = true
            radioButton.id = it.days
            binding.radioGroup.addView(radioButton)
        }
    }


radio_button_rectangle:
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the line -->
    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/divider" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>


radio_group_rectangle:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/dp_1" android:color="@color/divider"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>


I have tried adding the Gravity.CENTER as well but the alignment does not change.Could you please let me know how to achieve as the below the screenshot

